# How to print songs index and author index at the last in song package in latex?

Tags: songbook

Generally by default song package used to print before the songs. How can we customize song package to get the desired result?

This is the sequence of the format i need first print all the songs, second print songs index and author index in the back (i.e after all the songs.) The class i am using crepbook.cls http://www.patacrep.com/en/index.php

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a small example of a document with an index? That would make it easier to attempt to answer your question.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code.